# Erro ao fazer relacionamento com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, relacionamento, laravel-blade

---

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::belongTo()

---

***Minhas Models***

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imovel extends Model
{
    //definindo nome da tabela na migration
    protected $table = 'imoveis';


    //definindo relacao do campo id_tipo
    public function tipo()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(Tipo::class);
    }

    //definindo relacao do campo id_cidade
    public function cidade()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(Cidade::class);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tipo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['titulo'];

    //definindo relaçao entre as tabelas
    public function imoveis()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Imovel', 'id_tipo');
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use  App\Models\Imovel;

class Cidade extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'estado', 'sigla'];

    //definindo relaçao entre as tabelas
    public function imoveis()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Imovel::class);
    }

}
```

***Meu controller***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Models\Imovel;
use App\Models\Cidade;

class ImovelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $imovel = new Imovel();
        $imoveis = Imovel::all();           
        return view('admin.imoveis.index', compact('imoveis'));
    }

    public function adicionar()
    {   
        $cidades = Cidade::all();
        return view('admin.imoveis.adicionar', compact('cidades'));
    }
}
```

***Minha Vew***

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
    <h1>Usuarios</h1>
    <table class="table table-stripped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Endereçõ</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <td></td>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($imoveis as $imovel)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $imovel->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $imovel->titulo }}</td>
            <td>{{ $imovel->descricao }}</td>
            <td>{{ $imovel->endereco }}</td>
            <td>{{ $imovel->cidade->nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ $imovel->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ number_format($imovel->valor, 2, ',', '.') }}</td>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ asset($imovel->imagem) }}" class="thumb">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.imoveis.editar', $imovel->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                <a onclick="javascript:if(confirm('Deja excluir este usuario')){window.location.href='{{ route('admin.imoveis.deletar', $imovel->id) }}';}" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    <hr>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.imoveis.adicionar') }}" class="btn btn-success">Novo</a>
@endsection
```

***Estou usando o Laravel 5.4***

Comment: Informe a versão do laravel na pergunta

Comment: Estou usando o 5.4

Comment: Troque esta linha `$imoveis = Imovel::all()` por `$imoveis = Imovel::with('tipo')->get()`. Caso seja o erro. Irei montar uma resposta explicando o problema

Comment: O erro mudou  `Call to undefined relationship [tipos] on model [App\Models\Imovel].`

Comment: Adicionei porém o erro persiste no mesmo.

Comment: Mude as linhas `$this->belongTo('App\Models\Tipo')` e `$this->belongTo('App\Models\Cidade')` no model Imovel para `$this->belongTo(Tipo::class);` e  `$this->belongTo(Cidade::class);`. Acrescente o use de ambos.

Comment: Está apresentando esse erro: `Call to undefined relationship [tipos] on model [App\Models\Imovel].` novamente.

Comment: Atualiza seu model Imovel na pergunta para eu ver como ficou

Comment: Já atualizei as models.

Comment: Você precisa adicionar os use App\Models\Cidade e use App\Models\Tipo logo após o namespace

Comment: Já olhei no phpmyadmin e existe a relação entre as tabelas não estou conseguindo listar fazendo um inner join. Obs( o erro continua o mesmo).

Comment: As suas relações estão faltando configurar, porque você não seguiu a nomenclatura do `Laravel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se resolve informando o nome do campo referenciado na relação, pois pelo padrão o Laravel identifica os campos relacionados pela nomenclatura tabela_id

Exemplo:

```
public function tipo()
{
    return $this->belongTo(Tipo::class, 'id_tipo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou um **"s"** no ***belongsTo*** de ambas as models.

Comment: Você fez na mão porque as relações estão faltando configurar!

Comment: Qual ponto na model eu devo arrumar para as relações ficarem automaticas?

Comment: coloque na sua pergunta todas as tabelas e suas relações eu dou um exemplo total!